# Implementing adchoice for VAST 3.0 Wrapper

Tags: vast

I'm trying to add adchoices for VAST 2.0 wrapper using jpeg image using nonlinear element under a creative element in VAST wrapper. I couldnt get it to working from 3 days. Can anybody help me in fixing below code, Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<NonLinearAds>
 <NonLinear height="200" width="300" minSuggestedDuration="00:00:30">
   <StaticResource creativeType="image/png">
     https://example.com/image.png
   </StaticResource>
   <NonLinearClickThrough>
      https://example.com
   </NonLinearClickThrough>
 </NonLinear>
</NonLinearAds>
```

Update:

I'm trying to use icons to display adchoices which are supported in VAST3.0/4.0 
here is the below example tag i'm using. According to vast 3.0 documentation here https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VASTv3_0.pdf under 2.4.3.2 section icons are supported by both inline and wrappers but my code is working with inline ads but not working with wrapper ads. Am i doing something wrong. Please help me thanks in advance.

```
<VAST version="3.0">
    <Ad id="602833">
        <Wrapper>
            <AdSystem>Testing</AdSystem>
            <VASTAdTagURI>
                <![CDATA[https://vast.inline.url]]>
            </VASTAdTagURI>
            <Impression>http://myTrackingURL/wrapper/impression</Impression>
            <Creatives>
                <Creative>
                    <Linear>
                        <VideoClicks>
                            <ClickTracking>http://myTrackingURL/wrapper/click</ClickTracking>
                        </VideoClicks>
                        <Icons>
                            <Icon program="AdChoices" height="15" width="100" xPosition="10" yPosition="20">
                                <StaticResource creativeType="image/png">
                                    <![CDATA[https://www.amarley.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/images/mini_logo.png.pagespeed.ce.-Dk9UNhwz-.png]]>
                                </StaticResource>
                                <IconClicks>
                                    <IconClickThrough>
                                        <![CDATA[
                                            http://example.com/more_info
                                        ]]>
                                    </IconClickThrough>
                                </IconClicks>
                            </Icon>
                        </Icons>
                    </Linear>
                </Creative>
            </Creatives>
        </Wrapper>
    </Ad>
</VAST>
```

I'm using google vast inspector for testing https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector

Comment: Are you talking about [AdChoice](http://youradchoices.com), then you are on the wrong path and need to read about [2.4.3 Industry Icon Support](https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VASTv3_0.pdf).

Comment: Hi @zyexal, thanks for document. I realised that i should use icons in vast 3.0, according to the document you shared icons are supported in both inline and wrapper, but when is tried the same icons are working if i place them in inline linear ad but not working in wrapper linear ad. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Please update your question or create a new one. We will need an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're doing right now. Including the full VAST and information about the player resp. the test environment.

Comment: Thanks @zyexal. I updated the question.

Comment: @zyexal what am i missing? I don't see anything missing according to doc. Only AdSystem, VASTAdTagURI and Impression are mandatory everything else are optional.

Comment: I'm sorry, mixed Wrapper requirements with InLine requirements - my comment was wrong and I've deleted it. It could be an issue with the google player?!? Beside this I'm out of ideas and would need to create sample project by my own, which I don't have time for :(

Comment: I think we have seen breaking changes in the IMA SDKin implementing icons in VAST 3. According to the [IAB VAST 3 spec](https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VASTv3_0.pdf), Icons can be implemented as `<StaticResource>` `<IFrameResource>` or `<HTMLResource>`. We are only seeing <StaticResource> working. In 2017 we were able to insert an icon with an IFrame... but using `<StaticResource>`. Which is weird and seems out of spec, but that is how Campaign Manager (DCM) tags generated VAST 3 icons. It worked and now it's not. Specifically, our iframe loads but the js within it does not. If